# Encode any character to numbers/Latin and decode it back

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I have a UTF8 string that contains non-English symbols. I need to convert them to Latin/numbers and then get them back.

I tried `htmlentities('字')`

The result is `&aring;&shy;�`, but I need something like `x3445` so I can use `html_entity_decode()` or something similar that will return the original character.

How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: Have you tried using htmlentities with charset parameter set to UTF-8? Otherwise it assumes latin1.

Comment: tried `htmlentities('字', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')`. It returned character itself.

Comment: Did it with `mb_convert_encoding('字', 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, htmlentities will only encode characters that have a named entity. To convert everything else to a numeric entity, you can use `mb_encode_numericentities`. For example,

```
$string = mb_encode_numericentity(htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), array (0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of the htmlentities function allows you to set the charset that you would like to use for the conversion. [See http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)